# Как сохранять последние действия?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет и доброго дня!

Написал приложение, которое определяет мое местоположение и отправляет данные в БД. При сворачивании приложения на жизненных циклах `On Pause On Stop` я написал метод который также заставляет приложение определять местоположение и отправять их в БД. Проблем нет, проверил через логи все получилось. Насколько это правильно или нет это другой вопрос. Так вот, открывается приложение в `OnCreate`, есть  кнопка которая по нажатию запускает цикл и делает кнопку невидимой, но стоит свернуть и развернуть приложение, то кнопка видна. Почему???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При сворачивании срабатывают [принципы](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php) `жизненного цикла` `Activity`.

Раз у вас БД уже работает, создайте таблицу хранения настроек, в котором будет поле для состояния требуемой кнопки и всего одна строка. Скрываете кнопку, в БД устанавливаете(обновляете), например, `false`(поле `boolean`) или 0 (поле `int`). Перед показом в `onCreate` проверяете значение в БД. Если `true`(поле `boolean`) или 1 (поле `int`) показываете кнопку, если `false` - не показываете. Так можно хранить требуемое состояние приложения без `Bundle` и `SharedPreference`.

Comment: Я использую удаленную базу Mysql и мне не совсем ясна ваша мысль .Не могли бы вы  более корректно или с каким либо наглядным примером показать

Comment: ну вы же как-то работаете с БД? там есть таблицы, их создаете вы, делаете запросы, вставку, обновление. Или я не так понял, что с БД у вас все в порядке?

Comment: Да не я понел что вы имете ввду создам таблицу и одну булиновую строку установю её по дефалту false а дальше непонел что делать и как что проврять)

Comment: Создаете метод, который лезет в БД, в нужную таблицу, проверяете есть ли там нужное значение и возвращаете его через этот метод.

Comment: вы не совсем понели о чем я и более запутали .Я понел о чем вы я ставлю в БД булиан  и если сворачиваю развчиваю то по булиану я уже знаю отображать мне его или нет .Но это неправльнож

Comment: Скорее вего я ввопросе написал не так

Comment: в любом случае вам надо дать понять Activity когда что-то показывать, а когда что-то не показывать, верно?

Comment: Тимур я задал нов вопрос и там более подробно расписал !Я думаю вы на этот вопрос ответели верно ,но суть впроса не вэтом была .Я не грамотно составил вопрос